# Is it possible to Import file in JS file using URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have little older version of vue.js ("vue": "^2.2.2") defined in package.json

Which I access in my JS like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

But, I like to quickly test if things are working fine with newer version of vue.js.

```
import Vue from '//unpkg.com/vue@2.4.1'
```

If not possible, any better ways?

Comment: Any reason not to update (npm) to newer version, testing, and, if any problem, rollback (version control) to previous version? Regards.

Comment: To do this you want to remove the `import Vue from 'vue'` code and add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>` to your page, before the Vue initialization.

Comment: @DanielD I tried to do that first, but for some reason with my webpack setup I was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [node-multidep](https://github.com/joliss/node-multidep) project aims to solving this problem.

Create a json file `test/multidep.json`

```
{
  "path": "test/multidep_modules",
  "versions": {
    "vue": ["2.2.2", "2.4.1"]
  }
}
```

then:

```
npm install --save-dev multidep
./node_modules/.bin/multidep test/multidep.json
```

and finally in your js file, uncomment the line of the vue version you want to use:

```
var multidepRequire = require('multidep')('test/multidep.json')

var Vue = multidepRequire('vue', '2.2.2')
// var Vue = multidepRequire('vue', '2.4.1')
```